# Please explain the output. Long.toHexString()

Tags: java, hex

when i run the following code :

```
class Solution{
public static void main(String []argh){
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( Byte.MIN_VALUE ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( (byte)Math.pow(2,7) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( Byte.MAX_VALUE ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( (byte)Math.pow(2,63) -1 ) );

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( Short.MIN_VALUE ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( (short)Math.pow(2,15) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( Short.MAX_VALUE ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( (short)Math.pow(2,15) -1 ) );

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( Integer.MIN_VALUE ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( (-1*(int)Math.pow(2,31)) ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( Integer.MAX_VALUE ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( (int)Math.pow(2,31) -1 ) );

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( Long.MIN_VALUE ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( (-1*(long)Math.pow(2,63)) ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( Long.MAX_VALUE ) );
    System.out.println( Long.toHexString( (long)Math.pow(2,63) -1 ) );

    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
ffffffffffffff80
80
7f
fffffffffffffffe

ffffffffffff8000
8000
7fff
ffffffffffff7fff

ffffffff80000000
ffffffff80000001
7fffffff
7ffffffe

8000000000000000
8000000000000001
7fffffffffffffff
7ffffffffffffffe
```

Can someone please explain why the length of HexStrings are varying? I know it is elementary, please explain the answer too. I am confused.

**EDIT| Sorry I was confused over this silly thing, i did not try to think.**

Comment: It doesn't left-pad with zero.

Comment: @cjstehno okay. and Why the value of `Long.toHexString( Short.MIN_VALUE ) ` is `ffffffffffff8000` while the value of `Long.toHexString( Short.MAX_VALUE ) ` is `7fff`? why one is shorter than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it doesn't include the preceding zeroes.

For example, `Byte.MAX_VALUE` is 127, which is represented as "7f". It could return that as "000000000000007F", but the designers must have decided that more people would want it without the initial zeroes.

You can see this behavior documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString%28long%29).

> This value is converted to a string of ASCII digits in hexadecimal (base 16) **with no extra leading 0s**.

Emphasis mine.

In the comments, you seem to be confused about why the `MIN_VALUE` lengths are so long. To explain this, consider `Byte.MIN_VALUE` and `BYTE.MAX_VALUE`.
`Byte.MIN_VALUE` is -128, and `Byte.MAX_VALUE` is 127. Since you pass these to `Long.toHexString`, which expects a `long` as its argument, *they get upcast to `long`s*. So the values that end up being converted to hex strings are the `long` values of -128 and 127, which are expressed using [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) as "ffffffffffffff80" and "7f" respectively.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to know. Thank you :)